# Extracting elements from list of dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, multi-index

In a column of a data frame, I have the following scores for each row of the data frame:

```
[{'score': 100, 'bonus': 10}, {'score': 60, 'bonus': 0}]
[{'score': 80, 'bonus': 20}, {'score': 90, 'bonus': 30}]
```

Output

The output would be two new columns for change in score and change in bonus for each row.  So row one would have df.delta_score = -40 and df.delta_bonus = -10 and row two would have df.delta_score = 10 and df.delta_bonus = 10.

```
[{'score': 100, 'bonus': 10}, {'score': 60, 'bonus': 0}, -40, -10]
[{'score': 100, 'bonus': 10}, {'score': 60, 'bonus': 0}, 10, 10]
```

I want to calculate the change in value for each for both score and bonus for each person (row) and generate the new column with the resulting value.  I am quite confused with this data type, as it seems to be a list of dictionaries, but since each dictionary has same keys I want to use an operator to calculate the difference.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you know whether the difference in bonus should be `10` or `-10` ?

Comment: What would your expected output be, not in words, but if you could actually show numerically what you would expect?

Comment: as David says - please give the expected output as part of the post.

Comment: Edited to include output

Answer (score 1):

We will simply create two new columns `Bonus` and `Score`. You can use list comprehension with `.get()` to retrieve the value according to the keys `bonus` and `score`. Then, subtract the second value from the first value by subscribing `[1]` and subtracting `[0]`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dict_col': [[{'score': 100, 'bonus': 10}, {'score': 60, 'bonus': 0}],
                                [{'score': 80, 'bonus': 20}, {'score': 90, 'bonus': 30}]]})
df['Bonus'] = df['dict_col'].apply(lambda x: [d.get('bonus') for d in x][1] - [d.get('bonus') for d in x][0])
df['Score'] = df['dict_col'].apply(lambda x: [d.get('score') for d in x][1] - [d.get('score') for d in x][0])
df
Out[1]: 
                                            dict_col  Bonus  Score
0  [{'score': 100, 'bonus': 10}, {'score': 60, 'b...    -10    -40
1  [{'score': 80, 'bonus': 20}, {'score': 90, 'bo...     10     10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `explode` then we get the dataframe

```
s = df['Col'].explode()
calcu = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index)
calcu
Out[170]: 
   score  bonus
0    100     10
0     60      0
1     80     20
1     90     30
```

After this you can do

```
calcu.groupby(level=0)...(calculation follow by groupby)
```